# Need to Trim Java String

Tags: java

I need help in trimming a string url.

Let's say the String is `http://myurl.com/users/232222232/pageid`

What i would like returned would be `/232222232/pageid`

Now the 'myurl.com' can change but the `/users/` will always be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use `substring` and `indexOf("/users/")`.

```
String url = "http://myurl.com/users/232222232/pageid";
String lastPart = url.substring(url.indexOf("/users/") + 6);

System.out.println(lastPart);     // prints "/232222232/pageid"
```

---

A slightly more sophisticated variant would be to let the `URL` class parse the url for you:

```
URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com/users/232222232/pageid");
String lastPart = url.getPath().substring(6);

System.out.println(lastPart);     // prints "/232222232/pageid"
```

---

And, a third approach, using regular expressions:

```
String url = "http://myurl.com/users/232222232/pageid";
String lastPart = url.replaceAll(".*/users", "");

System.out.println(lastPart);     // prints "/232222232/pageid"
```

Comment: this one is great because it just cuts from the start of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.replaceAll(".*/users(/.*/.*)", "$1");
```

Comment: The second `/.*` is unnecessary. Besides, why use capturing groups at all? See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688005/need-to-trim-java-string/7688027#7688027) :-)

Comment: True, it is not necessary, but I think capturing groups are more understandable in terms of knowing what you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

```
String rest = url.substring(url.indexOf("/users/") + 6);
```

Comment: The OP wants to keep the last slash from `/users/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split(String regex,int limit)` which will split the string around the pattern in `regex` at most `limit` times, so...

```
String url="http://myurl.com/users/232222232/pageid";
String[] parts=url.split("/users",1);
//parts={"http://myurl.com","/232222232/pageid"}
String rest=parts[1];
//rest="/232222232/pageid"
```

The limit is there to prevent strings like `"http://myurl.com/users/232222232/users/pageid"` giving answers like `"/232222232"`.

Comment: I would add a limit argument (`1`) to that `split` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.indexOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) and [`String.substring()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) in order to achieve this:

```
String pattern = "/users/";
String url = "http://myurl.com/users/232222232/pageid";
System.out.println(url.substring(url.indexOf(pattern)+pattern.length()-1);
```